# How can I store mysql results in different individual variables with one connection to the databse?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, variables

I am currently working on a personal project and I need your help.
After a lot of research I can't seem to find a proper solution to my problem(probably because I am not very good php developer - i am still learning).

Ok so I need to get 3 post titles from my database and store each one of them in individual variables. I need them to be individual because I want to use them in different parts of my website.
I have managed to do this but only by doing three different queries to the databse wich i suppose its bad. Is there a way to send one query to the databse and store them at once inside different variables?
I tried to do this with an array and although I was close enough I didn't seem to get this working.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC limit 0,1');
    $sslider_title1='';
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $sslider_title1 = $row['postTitle'];
    }
}   
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC limit 1,2');
    $sslider_title2='';
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $sslider_title2 = $row['postTitle'];
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC limit 2,3');
    $sslider_title3='';
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $sslider_title3 = $row['postTitle'];
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So in order to get this running with one query i must do

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC limit 0,3');
    $sslider_title1='';
    $sslider_title2='';
    $sslider_title3='';
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        \\ This is the part that I can't seem to solve :P
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using loops when you're just fetching one row of results?

Comment: Shouldn't the second query be `LIMIT 1, 1`, and the third one `LIMIT 2,1`?

Comment: Because i need it to loop so the next slide will get the next 3 post title names but i m building a "rough" version at the moment to see how its working and finalize it. Yeah the limits were wrong, i found out later too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, do not use variables with such names. 
What you need is `array`:

```
$titles = array();
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC limit 0,3');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $titles[] = $row['postTitle'];
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can use

```
echo $titles[0];
echo $titles[1];
echo $titles[2];
```

for each of you titles.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm. What is wrong with my variable name? I don't know what you mean! Thanks in advance again!

Comment: Of course you can use vars like `$var1, $var2, $var3` but it's not a good practice. Always use arrays for storing data of same kind - it's more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store it in a variable this could be your answer:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC limit 0,3');
    $sslider_title1='';
    $row = $stmt->fetch()
    $sslider_title1 = $row['postTitle'];

    $sslider_title2='';
    $row = $stmt->fetch()
    $sslider_title3 = $row['postTitle'];

    $sslider_title3='';
    $row = $stmt->fetch()
    $sslider_title3 = $row['postTitle'];

}
```

If you also don't know how many results you will get you may still use a loop:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC limit 0,3');

    for($i=0;$row = $stmt->fetch();$i++){
        $sslider_title{$i}=$row['postTitle'];
    }
}
```

But I really really recommend you use an array.